# How to add color inside an icon?

Tags: css

I'm trying to color the background of an icon (from [material-icons](https://material.io/icons/)) but not beyond its outline (images illustration below).

As shown on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzeay42e/), I was only able to color the background but it does not fit the icon perfectly.

```
.material-icons {
  background:white;
}
```

Start :

[image]

What I try to get:

[image]

What I succeed to do :

[image]

I did not find a filled version of the icon. Ideally I don't want to use an other font just to answer that problem. Is it possible to do that in CSS or do I have to use a different version of the icon?

Comment: try css border-radius: 10px or something like that so as to make the background less rectangular.

Comment: The problem is that the icons looks like this, I mean, you need a SVG instead. Try looking into iconfinder, there will be something for sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using absolute positioning, a 15px by 15px div, and border-radius 50% worked for me in JSFiddle.

[image]

HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="block">
  <div class="icon">
    <p class="iconfix">
      <i class="material-icons" style="color:green">check_circle</i>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}

.icon {
  background: #fff;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
}

.iconfix {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.2em;
  left: -0.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make the parent div circular and then give it a background color. Use:

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/507fsp46/

Comment: apply the background color to .block, or apply everything, border-radius, height, width AND background color to .material-icons

Comment: That's better but it does not perfectly fit the icon. There is round white corner.

Comment: It seems like the icon has some sort of margin... it's not nice, but this works https://jsfiddle.net/67ko9e5g/

Answer (score 0):

Try including the CSS style `border-radius`.

[Relevant Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gt3xc89/).

Otherwise, you can find a PNG/SVG version of the icon and colour that in.

Comment: That's better but it does not perfectly fit the icon. There is a round white corner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that your icon looks like this, it is a circle into a square.

Try with [this SVG](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/103183/accept_check_checkround_ok_yes_icon#size=128)
Or [this one](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1579798/check_checkmark_icon#size=128).

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}

.whiteBackground {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.cls-1
{fill:green;}

.cls-2{fill:#fff;}

.orange{
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="whiteBackground">
<svg enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" height="24px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g><g><path d="M12,0C5.373,0,0,5.373,0,12c0,6.628,5.373,12,12,12c6.627,0,12-5.372,12-12C24,5.373,18.627,0,12,0z M19.754,9.561    l-8.607,8.607c-0.176,0.177-0.462,0.177-0.637,0l-1.272-1.285c-0.175-0.176-0.462-0.464-0.636-0.642l-2.96-3.112    c-0.087-0.087-0.133-0.21-0.133-0.327c0-0.115,0.046-0.227,0.133-0.314l1.297-1.169c0.088-0.09,0.205-0.134,0.321-0.134    c0.114,0.001,0.228,0.046,0.315,0.134l2.936,2.995c0.175,0.178,0.461,0.178,0.637,0l6.699-6.681c0.176-0.177,0.461-0.177,0.636,0    l1.272,1.285C19.93,9.094,19.93,9.384,19.754,9.561z" fill="green"/></g></g></svg>
  </div>
  
<svg class="orange" data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 128 128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><style></style></defs><title/><circle class="cls-1" cx="68.31" cy="64" r="60"/><polygon class="cls-2" points="61.19 88.14 89.09 42.49 83.8 40.12 59.56 80.23 46.27 72.19 43.08 77.46 61.19 88.14"/></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to directly draw a circle that matches icon's contour inside the svg. The first `<path/>` inside a material's icon is the square box surrounding the actual icon's path. This method replaces it with a circle slightly smaller than the icon's contour, then filling it with some color. For example:

```
<svg 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    height="24px" 
    viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
    width="24px" 
    fill="#000000">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/> <!-- square box to be replaced by a circle -->   
    <path 
        d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-2 15l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"/>
</svg>
```

Is replaced by:

```
<svg 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    height="24px" 
    viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
    width="24px" 
    fill="#000000">
    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="8" fill="#ffffff"/>
    <path 
        d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-2 15l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"/>
</svg>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #6b6b69;
}
```

```html
<svg 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    height="64px" 
    viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
    width="64px" 
    fill="#000000">
    <circle 
        cx="12" 
        cy="12" 
        r="8" 
        fill="#ffffff"/>
    <path 
        d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-2 15l-5-5 1.41-1.41L10 14.17l7.59-7.59L19 8l-9 9z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a radial-gradient background:

```css
background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,1) 51%, rgba(128,128,128,1) 53%);
```

This worked great in the example mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}

.block i {
  color : green !important;
}

.material-icons{
  background:white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="block">
    <i class="material-icons" style="color:green">check_circle</i>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzeay42e/1/)

Hope this helps.